# Can I get multiple outputs using apache camel?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, netty

I am using apache camel route. In which I have written a socket having parameters as encoder and decoder of netty.

I am giving input as a string and I want to get two strings as output. Encoder and decoder are producing two outputs, But on the route, I am getting first output only not the second one.

Is there any way to get multiple outputs for a single input in apache camel route?

Here is my route:

```
<post uri="/testaddstring">
     <route id="testaddstring">
            <script>
               <groovy>
                  <![CDATA[
                    String originalFileContent =(String)exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                    exchange.getIn().setBody(originalFileContent)
                                    System.out.println("in test add");
                                ]]>
                                </groovy>
                            </script>
                             <to uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5030?sync=true&amp;encoder=#i8583Encoder&amp;decoder=#i8583Decoder"/> 
                        </route>
                    </post>
```

Socket:

```
<route id="i8583SocketService">
    <from
        uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5030?sync=true&amp;encoder=#iEncoder&amp;decoder=#iDecoder" />
    <to
        uri="log:i8583SocketService?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true&amp;multiline=true" />      
</route>
```

Comment: can you post your full route so we can understand and propose a solution.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you **send 1 message** to a Camel route and you want to **get 2 messages from it**, you generally have to use the [**Splitter EIP**](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc) that splits your original message in multiple parts and routes these parts as individual messages.